Using layouts in Vue-3
I am trying to implement layouts in a vue-3 application.
Based on this solution, I created a simple layout file:
AppLayoutDashboard.vue:
<template>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red">
    <h1>AppLayoutDashboard.vue</h1>

    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>

In order to use it in some view, I to:
HomeView.vue:
<template>
  <app-layout-dashboard>

    <!-- VIEW CODE HERE -->

  </app-layout-dashboard>
</template>

I want to make it more flexible and move it to App.vue. If I move directly the <app-layout-dashboard> tag to this file, everything works fine.
However, I want it to be loaded dynamically. In order to do so, I thought to add a new attribute to routes array:
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,
    meta:{
      layout: 'AppLayoutDashboard',

    }
  },

I tried to use <component :is="layout"> (I retrieve layout from routing), but it doesn't work.  Any suggestion?

The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . This isn't shown, "I retrieve layout from routing". It's unknown why it doesn't work and what this actually means. Are there errors? You may have better chances adding a layout outside RouterView, as it won't be remounted on route change, which is generally a good thing for a layout

I had what I think is a similar issue to what you are describing, and I found this article very useful.
You do not need to insert the layouts directly on each page or view. Instead, create a Container layout:
// src/layouts/AppContainerLayout.vue

<template>
    <component :is="this.$route.meta.layoutComponent">
        <slot />
    </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "AppContainerLayout"
}
</script>

Then, update your App.vue file to include the Container layout:
// src/App.vue

<script setup>
import AppContainerLayout from './layouts/AppContainerLayout.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <AppContainerLayout>
    <RouterView />
  </AppContainerLayout>
</template>

Next, you can set up your router the same way you described but now you can add a call to a middleware to load the layout previously associated with the selected route:
// src/router/router.js

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import { loadLayoutMiddleware } from "./middleware/loadLayoutMiddleware";
import HomeView from "../views/HomeView.vue";
import AnotherView from "../views/AnotherView.vue";
import NotFoundView from "../views/NotFoundView.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: HomeView,
    meta: {
      layout: "AppLayoutDashboard",
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/another_view",
    name: "Another",
    component: AnotherView,
  },
  {
    path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
    name: "NotFound",
    component: NotFoundView,
    meta: {
      layout: "AppLayoutError",
    },
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach(loadLayoutMiddleware);

export default router;

This is the layout middleware associated with the router that I found in the repository from the same article with a minor update to load the default layout when no layout is declared within the route:
// src/router/middleware/loadLayoutMiddleware.js

export async function loadLayoutMiddleware(route) {
  try {
    let layout = route.meta.layout || "DefaultLayout";

    let layoutComponent = await import(`@/layouts/${layout}.vue`);
    route.meta.layoutComponent = layoutComponent.default;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error occurred in processing of layouts: ", e);
    console.log("Mounted DefaultLayout");
    let layout = "DefaultLayout";
    let layoutComponent = await import(`@/layouts/${layout}.vue`);
    route.meta.layoutComponent = layoutComponent.default;
  }
}

You can take out the logs once you check that it works properly.
Remember to clean your views from any references to layouts
// src/views/HomeView.vue:

<template>
    <!-- VIEW CODE HERE -->
</template>

Finally, the only thing missing at this point is to create the custom layouts but you have that covered:
// src/layouts/AppLayoutDashboard.vue

<template>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red">
    <h1>AppLayoutDashboard.vue</h1>

    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>

// src/layouts/DefaultLayout.vue

<template>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red">
    <h1>DefaultLayout.vue</h1>

    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>

// src/layouts/AppLayoutError.vue

<template>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red">
    <h1>AppLayoutError.vue</h1>

    <slot/>
  </div>
</template>

